# Try to update a 18.04 server but PostgreSQL no longer a release file

Tags: apt, updates, do-release-upgrade

I have a server using Ubuntu Server 18.04  that I have to upgrade to 20.04.

The problem is when I tried to update, Postgresql no longer have a release file for Bionic.

What is the best way to go forward? I can think only this 3 choices, if possible:

1. Do 'do-release-upgrade' without updating.
2. Uncomment 'postgersql' package, and 'do-release-upgrade', and later updating postgresql.
3. Uninstall 'postgresql' and do 'do-release-upgrade'

Comment: Once a release reaches EOL or EOSS (*18.04 reached that many months ago*), third party sources are free to *drop* support thus errors can be expected (*as you waited too long*). For best results on a *release-upgrade*, all 3rd party packages & sources should be removed (ie. return your system to official Ubuntu repository software, as that is what is QA tested*) then the *release-upgrade* performed, then any 3rd party software added back if still required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Please note:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is EOSS for many architectures & EOL for others, thus main archives have not all been *dropped* or *moved* yet, alas you gave few specifics; this the EOL or *unsupported* options may or may not apply for you based on details you didn't provide (ie. architecture & repository your error applies to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu uses versioned postgresql like so:

```
ii  postgresql                                     14+238                                       all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-10                                  10.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                       amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 10 server
ii  postgresql-12                                  12.14-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                       amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 12 server
ii  postgresql-14                                  14.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                        amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Source Relational Database
ii  postgresql-client-10                           10.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                       amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 10
ii  postgresql-client-12                           12.14-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                       amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 12
ii  postgresql-client-14                           14.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                        amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 14
```

So it may get removed, but you'll be able to re-install it once you've upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/ZN4OigxPJA236qlg%40msg.df7cb.de

You need to change repository in apt to:

`deb https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg main`